# Alamofire 3 como ir buscar os erros caso existam na chamada ao serviço(Swift2)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Tenho  o seguinte código para fazer a chamada ao servidor

```
   Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
        .responseJSON{ request, response, result in
           response in
            if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value {

                    let post = JSON(value)
                    print(post[0])
            }
            else
            {
                 print("**ERRO**")
            }
    }
```

A minha pergunta é como posso saber se houve erros na comunicação e colocar um time out, caso esteja a demorar muito.

Ja experimentei o seguinte código para ir buscar os possíveis erros:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString, parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
.responseJSON { request, response, result in
    switch result {
    case .Success(let JSON):
        print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
    case .Failure(let data, let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Mas obtenho o seguinte erro:

Contextual type for closure argument list expects 1 argument, but 3 were specified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O equívoco foi só mesmo no `completionHandler` do método `responseJSON`. Deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: ["foo": "bar"]).responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .Success(let data):
        // Sucesso
    case .Failure(let error):
        // Error
    }
}
```

Agora, para definir um *timeout*, você precisa definir primeiro as configurações dele, incluindo o tempo de *timeout* desejado, o que irá alterar a sua requisição. Algo assim:

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20
configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 20

let alamoFireManager: Alamofire.Manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
```

E então, sua requisição passará a ser feita por este objeto desta forma:

```
alamoFireManager.request(.GET, url, parameters: ["foo": "bar"]).responseJSON { response in
    // Restante do código...
}
```